# Hibernate 4 second level cache with memchached

Tags: java, hibernate, heroku, memcached, spymemcached

I have a spring application on heroku (seems like there is no way to use ehCache there). I found several projects on github like hibernate-memcached for the second level cache, but they have just few stars on github and I'm not sure if they are not buggy.

Would you recommend anything for java + hibernate 4 second level cache based on memcached?

Comment: Why not using Hazelcast as your 2nd level cache?

Comment: heroku supports only memcached with his memcachier addon. If I use Hazelcast I should set up my own server somewhere for caching. That's not an option I think. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/kwon37xi/hibernate4-memcached

I made this.

One of heroku user sent me an email that he was using this library.
I have never been used heroku, but anyway I think this library work fine with heroku.

I heard heruku memcached requires authentication, refer to this wiki page https://github.com/kwon37xi/hibernate4-memcached/wiki/SpyMemcachedAdapter about authentication.